# Get two teams greatest lead throughout game

Tags: c#, list, timespan

I have a `Game` that involves 2 teams. The `Game` has a List of `ScoreEvents`. Each ScoreEvent is a 1 point for the Team that scored. I need to know what the Max lead score was for each team (0 if they never had the lead). The `ScoreEvents` List is ordered by `TimeSinceStart`.

```
public class ScoreEvent
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeSinceStart { get; set; }
}

public void GetMaxScoreLead()
{
    var ScoreEvents = new List<ScoreEvent>
    {
        new ScoreEvent { TeamId = 0, TimeSinceStart = new TimeSpan(100)},
        new ScoreEvent { TeamId = 0, TimeSinceStart = new TimeSpan(200)},
        new ScoreEvent { TeamId = 0, TimeSinceStart = new TimeSpan(300)},

        //Score at 300 ticks is 3-0 to TeamdId = 0

        new ScoreEvent { TeamId = 1, TimeSinceStart = new TimeSpan(400)},
        new ScoreEvent { TeamId = 1, TimeSinceStart = new TimeSpan(500)},
        new ScoreEvent { TeamId = 1, TimeSinceStart = new TimeSpan(600)},
        new ScoreEvent { TeamId = 1, TimeSinceStart = new TimeSpan(700)},

        //Score at 700 ticks is a 3-4 to TeamId = 1

        new ScoreEvent { TeamId = 0, TimeSinceStart = new TimeSpan(800)},
        new ScoreEvent { TeamId = 0, TimeSinceStart = new TimeSpan(900)},
        new ScoreEvent { TeamId = 0, TimeSinceStart = new TimeSpan(1000)},
        new ScoreEvent { TeamId = 0, TimeSinceStart = new TimeSpan(1100)}

        //Score at 1100 ticks is 7-4 to TeamId 0
    };
}
```

So for the example above the answers for greatest lead per team would be:

1. TeamId (0) = 3 greatest lead
2. TeamId (1) = 1 greatest lead

EDIT: Code that I've got to. I know I need to keep track of the current score somewhere.

```
var teamZeroLargestLead = 0;
var teamOneLargestLead = 0;

var internalTeamZeroLargestLead = 0;
var internalTeamOneLargestLead = 0;

foreach (var scoreEvent in scoreEvents.OrderBy(x => x.TimeSinceStart))
{
    if (scoreEvent.TeamId == 0)
    {
        if (internalTeamOneLargestLead > teamOneLargestLead)
        {
             teamOneLargestLead = internalTeamOneLargestLead;
             internalTeamOneLargestLead = 0;
        }

        internalTeamZeroLargestLead += 1;
     }
     else
     {
        if(internalTeamZeroLargestLead > teamZeroLargestLead)
        {
            teamZeroLargestLead = internalTeamZeroLargestLead;
            internalTeamZeroLargestLead = 0;
        }

        internalTeamOneLargestLead += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, share the code, what have you tried to solve the problem

Comment: 2 seconds, adding it now

Comment: Also, do the ticks always have 100 interval?

Comment: Why is TimeSpan relevant to your question? Why not simply count which team scored? Basically group by teamId and get length of each group.

Comment: TeamId (0) = should be 3?

Comment: @Neolisk because thats just a difference between the total final scores. i need to know what each teams bigest lead was at any point in the game

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski nope thats just an example, times can be anything but in order

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski code ive tried posted now in OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've slightly updated and simplified your algorithm with `foreach` loop and now it returns the correct result -  `teamZeroLead` is `3`, `teamOneLead` is `1`.

```cs
var teamZeroLead = 0;
var teamOneLead = 0;
var teamZeroScore = 0;
var teamOneScore = 0;

foreach (var scoreEvent in scoreEvents.OrderBy(x => x.TimeSinceStart))
{
    if (scoreEvent.TeamId == 0)
    {
        teamZeroScore++;
        teamZeroLead = Math.Max(teamZeroLead, teamZeroScore - teamOneScore);
    }
    else
    {
         teamOneScore++;
         teamOneLead = Math.Max(teamOneLead, teamOneScore - teamZeroScore);
    }
}
```

At every loop iteration you are calculating the current score of every team, then calculate the lead value and assign it to the result value, if it's greater then previously calculated.

The same logic can be written using `Aggregate` method and value tuple, you can choose what is more readable and convenient for you

```cs
var result = scoreEvents.Aggregate((teamZeroLead: 0, teamOneLead: 0, teamZeroScore: 0, teamOneScore: 0),
    (scores, scoreEvent) =>
    {
        if (scoreEvent.TeamId == 0)
        {
            scores.teamZeroScore++;
            scores.teamZeroLead = Math.Max(scores.teamZeroLead, scores.teamZeroScore - scores.teamOneScore);
        }
        else
        {
            scores.teamOneScore++;
            scores.teamOneLead = Math.Max(scores.teamOneLead, scores.teamOneScore - scores.teamZeroScore);
        }

        return scores;
    });
```

After execution you can get the result values using `result.teamZeroLead` and `result.teamOneLead`

Comment: Marked this as the anwer as it was easy to modify for a team scoring an own goal i.e. minus the score by one. Also needed to check the first event for each team to ensure their first event wasnt an own goal which would make their start score be -1 instead of 0

Answer (score 2):

```
var leftTeamId = ScoreEvents.First().TeamId
var res = ScoreEvents
  .OrderBy(x => x.TimeSinceStart)
  .Aggregate(
    (max: 0, min: 0, curr: 0), 
    (acc, currSE)  => {
        var  curr = currSE.TeamId == leftTeamId
            ? acc.curr +1
            : acc.curr - 1;
        if(curr > acc.max)
        {
            return (curr, acc.min, curr);
        }
        else if (curr < acc.min)
        {
            return (acc.max, curr, curr);
        }
        return (acc.max, acc.min, curr);
    });
```

And for "left" team with id `leftTeamId` you use `res.max` for "right" team you use `Math.Abs(res.min)`:

1. TeamId (0) = `res.max` greatest lead
2. TeamId (1) = `Math.Abs(res.min)` greatest lead

I did not get rightTeamId, cause in theory only one team could have scored (but assumed that at least one did =).

Answer (score 2):

Since there are only two teams see if this approach satisfies your needs.

```
        int team1Score = 0;
        int team2Score = 0;
        int maximumLead = 0;
        int maximumLeadTeamId = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < ScoreEvents.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ScoreEvents[i].TeamId == 0)
            {
                team1Score++;
            }
            else
            {
                team2Score++;
            }
            int currentLead = Math.Abs(team1Score - team2Score);
            if (currentLead > maximumLead)
            {
                maximumLead = currentLead;
                maximumLeadTeamId = ScoreEvents[i].TeamId;
            }
        }
```

maximumLeadTeamId is the Id of the team with maximum lead throughout the game and maximumLead is the maximum goals difference between the two teams.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get a dictionary of team id to score at the specified timespan:

```
public static Dictionary<int, int> GetMaxScoreLead(IEnumerable<ScoreEvent> scoreEvents, TimeSpan time)
{
    var scoreDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    var grouping = scoreEvents.Where(e => e.TimeSinceStart <= time).GroupBy(e => e.TeamId);

    foreach (var group in grouping)
    {
        scoreDictionary.Add(group.Key, group.Count());
    }

    return scoreDictionary;
}
```

This code does not depend on the number of teams. You can trivially determine the winning team from this dictionary structure. For example:

```
var winningTeam = getScores.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

[image]